# Potterton EP3000 programmer HW and CH buttons not working

Tags: central-heating, boiler

I've got a Potterton EP3000 boiler and the programmer won't respond to me pressing the HW and CH buttons.

It was working fine until I switched off the power to the plugs (to do some electrics). After about an hour, when I switched the power back on, we tried to get the heating back on and no luck.

The clock shows up fine, and we can program the time and day of week. Setting it to 24-hours or twice and trying the CH or HW buttons has no effect.

Any ideas or suggestions on why this won't work are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by disconnecting the freeze sensor. There was a separate sensor attached to connections on the right hand side (I forget the numbers and I'm not at home now). If anyone is interested I can give more specific details.